# Best way to get the color where a mouse was clicked in AS3

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I have an image (mx) and i want to get the uint of the pixel that was clicked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an even simpler implementation. All you do is take a snapshot of the stage using the **draw()** method of bitmapData, then use **getPixel()** on the pixel under the mouse. The advantage of this is that you can sample anything that's been drawn to the stage, not just a given bitmap.

```
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.events.*;

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getColorSample);

function getColorSample(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(stage.width, stage.height);
    bd.draw(stage);
    var b:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bd);
    trace(b.bitmapData.getPixel(stage.mouseX,stage.mouseX));
}
```

Hope this is helpful!

---

**Edit**:

This edited version uses a single `BitmapData`, and removes the unnecessary step of creating a `Bitmap`. If you're sampling the color on `MOUSE_MOVE` then this is essential to avoid memory issues.

Note: if you're using a custom cursor sprite you'll have to use an  object other than 'state' or else you'll be sampling the color of the custom sprite instead of what's under it.

```
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.events.*;

private var _stageBitmap:BitmapData;

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getColorSample);

function getColorSample(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    if (_stageBitmap == null) {
        _stageBitmap = new BitmapData(stage.width, stage.height);
    }
    _stageBitmap.draw(stage);

    var rgb:uint = _stageBitmap.getPixel(stage.mouseX,stage.mouseY);

    var red:int =  (rgb >> 16 & 0xff);
    var green:int =  (rgb >> 8 & 0xff);
    var blue:int =  (rgb & 0xff);

    trace(red + "," + green + "," + blue);
}
```

Comment: I AM GOING TO KILL YOU !!!!!!!!!!!

Can anybody see why.... ;-) 

Tip: Always double check stackoverflow code before using it :-)

Comment: I'd throw in some simple bounds checking for good measure, to make sure you catch when your x and y are outside of the stage area.

Comment: You don't need to draw the entire stage just to grab one pixel value. Make the BitmapData 1x1 and pass a matrix and a clipRect to that draw call.

Answer (score 10):

A few minutes on the [BitmapData LiveDoc Page](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html) will take you where you need to go.  Once you have your image loaded into a Bitmap variable, you can access its BitmapData property.  Add a [Mouse Click Event](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#CLICK) Listener to the image and then use [BitmapData::getPixel](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html).  The example for getPixel shows how to convert the uint response to an rgb hex code.

Here's a modification of the Example given on the BitmapData page that worked for me (using mxmlc - YMMV):

```
package {
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class BitmapDataExample extends Sprite {
        private var url:String = "santa-drunk1.jpg";
        private var size:uint = 200;
        private var image:Bitmap;

        public function BitmapDataExample() {
            configureAssets();
        }

        private function configureAssets():void {
            var loader:Loader = new Loader();
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
            loader.load(request);
            addChild(loader);
        }

        private function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
            var loader:Loader = Loader(event.target.loader);
            this.image = Bitmap(loader.content);

            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this.clickListener);
        }

        private function clickListener(event:MouseEvent):void {
            var pixelValue:uint = this.image.bitmapData.getPixel(event.localX, event.localY)
            trace(pixelValue.toString(16));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This is not specific to Flex or mx:Image, and allows you to grab a pixel color value from any bitmap drawable object (provided you have permission):

```
private const bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(1, 1);
private const matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
private const clipRect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1);

public function getColor(drawable:IBitmapDrawable, x:Number, y:Number):uint
{
    matrix.setTo(1, 0, 0, 1, -x, -y)
    bitmapData.draw(drawable, matrix, null, null, clipRect);
    return bitmapData.getPixel(0, 0);
}
```

You could easily grab a pixel from the stage or your mx:Image instance. It's a lot more efficient than drawing the entire stage (or drawable object), and should be fast enough to hook up to MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE for instant visual feedback.

Comment: IMO this is definitely the superior answer due to the fact that it doesn't draw the entire stage and more precisely answers the question.