# How to find the color under the mouse in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

So, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78849/best-way-to-get-the-color-where-a-mouse-was-clicked-in-as3) article looks at how to get the color from an image in AS3, and one of the answers suggests a better way to grab colors using the 'draw' function of a BitmapData object.  But these are somewhat limiting, I'm trying to implement an eyedropper-type utility and need to be able to know what color the user is seeing at a certain pixel.

I've tried using draw() on the stage, but that doesn't include anything that's a child of the stage. 
Next, it occurred to me that I could just look at the children of the stage to find the foremost one that's under the mouse, and draw() that, but then we suddenly get into a possibly time consuming recursive search.
does anyone have any better ideas? 
The simplest/fastest/best way to find what color is being displayed under the mouse in Actionscript 3.

Comment: draw should work fine with children...

Comment: It seems Cay is right, because I wasn't using the alpha channel in my BitmapData object it looked like the children weren't being captured in draw().

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to get the color where a mouse was clicked in AS3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78849/best-way-to-get-the-color-where-a-mouse-was-clicked-in-as3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want this stack overflow question:

[Best way to get the color where a mouse was clicked in AS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78849/)

Comment: Isn't this same link Dogmatixed mentioned in his question?