# AS3: How to apply color from gradient spectrum to selected textfield text

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have defined a gradient color spectrum that I would like to use to change the color of a text selection in an input textfield. This is expected to act just like the colorpicker.

Comment: Do you want all the symbols in textfield to be colored uniformly, or do you want to apply gradient to the text as an image?

Comment: Did you write any code or you want we to write it for you...?

Answer (score 0):

See this one [Best way to get the color where a mouse was clicked in AS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78849/best-way-to-get-the-color-where-a-mouse-was-clicked-in-as3) for getting the selected color.

When you have it, simply apply `yourColor` to the text selection with a `TextFormat`:

```
var myFormat = new TextFormat();
myFormat.color = yourColor;

yourTextField.setTextFormat(myFormat,
                            yourTextField.selectionBeginIndex,
                            yourTextField.selectionEndIndex);
```